# FParsec default error messages

Tags: .net, f#, combinations, parser-combinators, fparsec

Let's say I am defining the following parser:

```
let identifier = many1Satisfy isLetter //match an identifier
let parser = identifier //our parser is only to match identifiers
test parser " abc" //the text to parse contains a leading space which should yield us an error
```

When parsing, an error ocurrs, as one would expect:

```
Failure: Error in Ln: 1 Col: 1
 abc
^
Unknown Error(s)
```

I am curious on why can't it decide the problem is that he's expecting a letter and can't find one. Am I expected to add that info somehow to the parser by myself?

Comment: Meanwhile the parser has evolved. You can solve this with `<?>` "error message" as is now explained on the FParsec website with almost the same situation as you describe here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as to why it can't tell you whats wrong:
I guess this is due to the "many1Satisfy" - you see this combinator wraps another parser and I guess it just don't know in which state of "many1" an error occured and not what error - so it says "Unknown Error(s)"

this should work:

```
let ws = spaces
let identifier = ws >>. (many1Satisfy isLetter) //match an identifier, ignore whitespaces infront
let parser = identifier //our parser is only to match identifiers
test parser " abc"
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to parse white spaces. I want to know why I'm getting an "Unknown Error" instead of an error stating he was not expecting the kind of characters he found.

Comment: oh sorry - I guess this is due to the "many1Satisfy" - you see this combinator wraps another parser and I guess it just don't know in which state of "many1" an error occured and not what error - so he says "at least one error" or "Unknown Error(s)" ;)

Comment: CKoenig is right. Please also see the explanation and examples at the top of http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/customizing-error-messages.html

Comment: A little nitpicking: many1Satisfy is a primitive that does NOT "wrap another parser". The problem here is that from the predicate function alone it is not possible to generate a useful error message (at least not without trying the predicate function on all chars).

Answer (score 0):

White space is not a regular character. In your case you need to ignore the white spaces and for that you need to compose your parser with the parser which ignores white spaces and use this new composed parser to parse the identifier.

Check **[4.6 Handling whitespace](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html)**

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to parse white spaces. I want to know why I'm getting an "Unknown Error" instead of an error stating he was not expecting the kind of characters he found.